# How to scrape dynamic javascript content on a website in python?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I need to scrape this website in python (https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/live) to get and save in a csv file the latest odds but it's a javascript dynamically updated content (AJAX? not so familiar with js...). I've tried with selenium and nothing worked.

I've found the js script handling all the data at this adress (https://static.winamax.fr/betting/client/1.31.1/12.main.js) which uses the webpackJsonp module so I guess the data is in ***json*** format (correct me if I'm wrong, again I'm not very familiar with javascript).

That displays all the infos but it's really messy and I can only read the titles (like "events live", "events to come", "favorites" etc) not the actual data from matchs, here is the raw version (a big one line code, that's why it more digestable to read with the link provided above)

```
(window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[12],{696:function(t,e,n){"use strict";var r=n(55),o=n.n(r),a=n(52),i=n(3),u=n(4),c=n.n(u),s=n(10),f=n(275);function l(t){return function(t){if(Array.isArray(t)){for(var e=0,n=new Array(t.length);e<t.length;e++)n[e]=t[e];return n}}(t)||function(t){if(Symbol.iterator in Object(t)||"[object Arguments]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(t))return Array.from(t)}(t)||function(){throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance")}()}function p(t,e,n){return e in t?Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:n,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):t[e]=n,t}var m=f.a.STANDARD,h=f.a.LIVE,v=f.a.FAVORITES,y=Object(a.createSelectorCreator)(a.defaultMemoize,s.j),d=[],E=function(t){return Object(a.createSelector)([function(t,e){return e.location.pathname},function(t,e){return e.match.params.sportId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.categoryId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.tournamentId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.hour}],function(e,n,r,o,a){return function(t){return function(e,n,r,o,a){return function(n){if("home"===t){if("live"===n)return{text:c()("EVENTS_LIVE"),type:h};if("edito"===n)return{text:c()("NEW_TITLE"),type:m};if("to_come"===n)return{text:c()("EVENTS_TO_COME"),type:m}}else if("live"===t){if("live"===n)return e.match(/favorites/)?{text:c()("CURRENT_FAVORITES"),type:v}:{text:c()("EVENTS_LIVE"),type:m};if("prematch"===n)return e.match(/favorites/)?{text:c()("TOCOME_FAVORITES"),type:v}:{text:c()("EVENTS_TO_LIVE"),type:m}}else if("tv"===t){if("live"===n)return e.match(/favorites/)?{text:c()("CURRENT_FAVORITES"),type:v}:{text:c()("EVENTS_LIVE"),type:h};if("prematch"===n)return e.match(/favorites/)?{text:c()("TOCOME_FAVORITES"),type:v}:{text:c()("EVENTS_TO_COME"),type:m}}else if("favorites"===t){if("live"===n)return{text:c()("CURRENT_FAVORITES"),type:v};if("prematch"===n)return{text:c()("TOCOME_FAVORITES"),type:v}}else if("catalog"===t){if("live"===n)return{text:c()("EVENTS_LIVE"),type:m};if("prematch"===n)return{text:c()("EVENTS_TO_COME"),type:m}}else if("calendar"===t)return{text:c()("NEXT_HOURS",{count:s.h.castNumber(a)}),type:m};return{text:void 0,type:m}}}}(t)(e,n,r,o,a)})},O=function(t){return Object(a.createSelector)([function(t,e){return e.match.params.sportId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.categoryId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.tournamentId}],function(e,n,r){return function(t){return function(e,n,r){return function(o){return"home"===t?"live"===o.hlType?"live":"highlight":["tv","favorites"].indexOf(t)>-1?"LIVE"===o.status?"live":"highlight":"live"===t?"LIVE"===o.status?"live":"prematch":"catalog"===t?(void 0!==r?a="tournament":void 0!==n?a="category":void 0!==e&&(a="sport"),"LIVE"===o.status?"live":a):"highlight";var a}}}(t)(e,n,r)})},b=function(t){return Object(a.createSelector)([function(t){return t.entities},function(t,e){return e.match.params.sportId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.categoryId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.tournamentId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.hour},function(t,e){return e.location.pathname}],function(e,n,r,o,a,i){var u,c=t;return["live","tv","catalog"].indexOf(t)>-1?i.indexOf("favorites")>-1?c="favorites":void 0!==o?(c="tournaments",u=o):void 0!==r?(c="categories",u=r):void 0!==n&&(c="sports",u=n):"calendar"===t&&(c="calendar",u=a),u?e[c][u]:e[c]})},g=function(t){return Object(a.createSelector)([function(t,e){return e.match.params.sportId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.categoryId},function(t,e){return e.match.params.tournamentId},function(t,e){return e.location.pathname}],function(e,n,r,o){var a="matches";return"live"===t?o.indexOf("favorites")>-1?a="liveMatches":void 0===r&&void 0===n&&void 0===e||(a="liveMatches"):"tv"===t&&(o.indexOf("favorites")>-1?a="tvMatches":void 0===r&&void 0===n&&void 0===e||(a="tvMatches")),a})},T=function(t){return Object(a.createSelector)([b(t),g(t),function(t){return t.entities.matches}],function(t,e,n){var r=t&&t[e]||d;return Object(i.map)(r,function(t){return n[t]})})},I=function(t){return y([T(t),function(t){return t.entities.sports},function(t){return t.entities.categories},function(t){return t.entities.tournaments}],function(t,e,n,r){return Object(i.reduce)(t,function(t,o){if(void 0!==o&&null!==o){var a=o.sportId,i=o.tournamentId,u=o.categoryId;if(99999!==a){var c,f=e[a];if(o.tvChannels&&(c=s.f.convertToLowerCase(o.tvChannels)),void 0!==f&&null!==f){var l=n[u];if(void 0!==l&&null!==l){var m=r[i];void 0!==m&&null!==m&&t.push(function(t){for(var e=1;e<arguments.length;e++){var n=null!=arguments[e]?arguments[e]:{},r=Object.keys(n);"function"===typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols&&(r=r.concat(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(n).filter(function(t){return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(n,t).enumerable}))),r.forEach(function(e){p(t,e,n[e])})}return t}({},o,{tvChannels:c,sportName:f.sportName,categoryName:l.categoryName,tournamentName:m.tournamentName}))}}}}return t},[])})},S=function(t){return Object(a.createSelector)([b(t),g(t),I(t)],function(t,e,n){return{isLoading:void 0===t||t&&void 0===t[e],isNull:null===t||t&&null===t[e]||!1,matches:n}})};e.a=function(t){return function(){return y([S(t),O(t),E(t),function(t){return t.entities.grids}],function(e,n,r,a){var u=e.matches,s=e.isLoading,f=e.isNull;if(s||f)return{list:d,isEmpty:0===u.length,isLoading:s,isNull:f};var p={default:function(){return!0}};"home"===t?p={live:["hlType","live"],edito:["hlType","edito"],to_come:function(t){return t&&"live"!==t.hlType&&"edito"!==t.hlType}}:"live"!==t&&"tv"!==t&&"catalog"!==t&&"favorites"!==t||(p={live:["status","LIVE"],prematch:["status","PREMATCH"]});var h=Object(i.reduce)(p,function(e,s,f){var p=Object(i.filter)(u,s);return p.length>0?("catalog"===t&&"prematch"===f||e.push({type:"separator",payload:{item:r(f)}}),p.forEach(function(r,a,i){if("catalog"===t){var u,s,f=i[a-1],l=o.a.unix(r.matchStart).format("l"),p=r.isOutright;a>0&&(u=o.a.unix(f.matchStart).format("l"),s=f.isOutright),"LIVE"!==r.status&&(r.isOutright?s!==p&&e.push({type:"separator",payload:{item:{text:c()("BETS_OUTRIGHTS"),type:m}}}):u!==l&&e.push({type:"separator",payload:{item:{text:o.a.unix(r.matchStart).format(c()("formats.dateShort")),type:m}}}))}e.push({type:n(r),payload:{item:r}})}),"home"===t&&"edito"===f&&a&&a.length&&e.push.apply(e,l(Object(i.map)(a,function(t){return{type:"grid",payload:{item:t}}})))):"home"===t&&0===p.length&&"edito"===f&&a&&a.length&&(e.push({type:"separator",payload:{item:{text:c()("NEW_TITLE"),type:m}}}),e.push.apply(e,l(Object(i.map)(a,function(t){return{type:"grid",payload:{item:t}}})))),e},[]);return{list:h,isEmpty:0===h.length,isLoading:s,isNull:f}})}}},837:function(t,e,n){"use strict";n.r(e);n(6);var r=n(0),o=n.n(r),a=n(12),i=n(4),u=n.n(i),c=n(277),s=n.n(c),f=n(274),l=n(111),p=n(35),m=n(696),h=n(712),v=n(171),y=n(698),d=n(694);function E(t){return(E="function"===typeof Symbol&&"symbol"===typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t){return typeof t}:function(t){return t&&"function"===typeof Symbol&&t.constructor===Symbol&&t!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof t})(t)}function O(t,e){for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e[n];r.enumerable=r.enumerable||!1,r.configurable=!0,"value"in r&&(r.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(t,r.key,r)}}function b(t,e){return!e||"object"!==E(e)&&"function"!==typeof e?function(t){if(void 0===t)throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called");return t}(t):e}function g(t){return(g=Object.setPrototypeOf?Object.getPrototypeOf:function(t){return t.__proto__||Object.getPrototypeOf(t)})(t)}function T(t,e){return(T=Object.setPrototypeOf||function(t,e){return t.__proto__=e,t})(t,e)}var I=function(t){function e(){return function(t,e){if(!(t instanceof e))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}(this,e),b(this,g(e).apply(this,arguments))}var n,a,i;return function(t,e){if("function"!==typeof e&&null!==e)throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function");t.prototype=Object.create(e&&e.prototype,{constructor:{value:t,writable:!0,configurable:!0}}),e&&T(t,e)}(e,r["Component"]),n=e,(a=[{key:"componentWillMount",value:function(){var t=this.props,e=t.location,n=t.match;this.dispatchRoute(n.params,e.pathname)}},{key:"componentWillReceiveProps",value:function(t){var e=t.match.params,n=t.location.pathname;this.props.location.pathname!==n&&this.dispatchRoute(e,n)}},{key:"dispatchRoute",value:function(t,e){var n=l.a.LIVE,r=t.sportId,o=t.categoryId,a=t.tournamentId;e.indexOf("favorites")>-1?n+=":favorites":void 0!==a?n+=":tournament:".concat(a):void 0!==o?n+=":category:".concat(o):void 0!==r&&(n+=":sport:".concat(r)),this.props.askRoute(n)}},{key:"render",value:function(){var t=this.props,e=t.isLoading,n=t.isNull,r=t.isEmpty,a=t.list;return e?o.a.createElement(s.a,{title:u()("DOCUMENT_TITLE.LIVE")},o.a.createElement(v.a,{loading:!0})):o.a.createElement(s.a,{title:u()("DOCUMENT_TITLE.LIVE")},o.a.createElement("section",{className:"event-list"},!n&&!r&&o.a.createElement(h.a,{items:a}),(n||r)&&o.a.createElement("p",{className:"no-results centered-message-betting"},u()("EVENTS_NO"))))}}])&&O(n.prototype,a),i&&O(n,i),e}();e.default=Object(f.a)(d.a,y.a,Object(a.connect)(function(){var t=Object(m.a)("live")();return function(e,n){return t(e,n)}},function(t){return{askRoute:function(e){t(p.a.send({route:e}))}}}))(I)}}]);
```

So I simply need to scrape this data and return it to pretty much the same format of the website (from the most global to the most refined data):

1. Total number of live games (all sports included) with all their infos, bets and odds available. Within this list I can select any game individually and see its infos, odds and bets available.
2. total number of live games by each sport (ex: football (8), basketball (6) ect..) with all their infos, bets and odds available.
3. A list of all live tournaments/leagues by each sport (ex: if footaball is selected, return british premier league, spanish liga, french ligue 1 ect ect) with all their infos, bets and odds available.
4. When a specific tournament/league is selected in a sport (ex: british premier league in football), display the list all of its live games with all their infos, bets and odds available.
5. Lastly, within this list of point 4/, I need like in point 1/ to be able to select any live game individually to see its infos, odds and bets available.

Any help, suggestions & ideas will be greatly appreciated.

j.d

Comment: For a dynamically generated site, you might want to either use Python with Selenium, or check the "Network" tab of Chrome's dev tools to see if you can find a call to a possible API the website might be using to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I've done that already and by checking the network tab that's how I retrieved the js script handling the data, but I couldn't find any api endpoint, and as mentionned previously I'm honestly not very familiar with javascript so that's pretty where I'm stuck right now

Answer (score 0):

The website https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/live gets 'fresh' data periodically using [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)  .

Navigate to the WS tab (under Network tab) and see the frames of data coming from the server to the client.

Try to use a WebSocket client like https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/ and point it to the site you try to scrape.

Comment: Thx for your precious answer! I was indeed assuming it was using a kind of websockets. Under the "headers" tab,  the request url points to:  wss://sports-eu-west-3.winamax.fr/sports-server/socket.io/?language=FR&version=1.31.1&EIO=3&transport=websocket  could it be the address providing the data? Then under the "frames" tab, the one after "headers"  the data is displayed (seems like in json format?) with red and green arrows (red = received data, green= sent data)

Comment: Yes - this is the URL you need to use. This JSON data that is pushed to the browser every ~1 sec.

Comment: thx a lot, but how can I extract ths JSON data pushed every 1 sec in python with selenium? just launching my python script itself and scrape, it takes more than 30 secs...  I've read your link and it says in order to connect you need a http proxy with a proxy port, how can I find them?

Comment: I dont think selenium is the right direction. I would give WS client a try. I assume that you do not have lots of experience with scraping nor with  WS so it will not be very easy... Look here for tools: https://github.com/lorien/awesome-web-scraping/blob/master/python.md#websocket

Comment: I've scraped a lot a websites with selenium and never had any pbs, I guess they were static sites. I've managed to get with WS client the number "40" type of data but I need the "42" type of data, the one pushed every sec (those numbers are in front on the receiving data in the frames tab), and contains all the useful infos, for ex:  42["m",{"odds":{"157316085":5.5,"157316086":1.01,"157322044":1.18,"157322045":3.05},"matches":{"15857644":{"remainingTime":"32:18","remainingTimeInPeriod":"12:18","score":"18:12","setScores":"18:12","moreBets":40},"16638645":{"matchtimeExtended":"90:00 +1:58"}}}]

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: share your code and explain what happens when you try to get the "42" data.

Comment: import json
import pprint
import websocket
from websocket import create_connection

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = create_connection('wss://sports-eu-west-3.winamax.fr/sports-server/'
'socket.io/"?language=FR&version=1.31.1&EIO=3&transport=websocket')
result = ws.recv()
print('Result: '.format(result))  (when I try to copy past the last 2 lines of codes multiple times in my code to get several results,  the connection get lost after 30secs, sometimes I receive 1 or 2 "42" data but that's it, contrary to the "40" which is always displayed) & don't how to get the specific "42" data

Comment: the "40" data displayed is fine: Result: 0{"sid":"NdyhJwnqk_yKUfrER0Os","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
Result: 40 THEN I have 2 errors saying always "send:" with a code like this one:
send: b'\x88\x82s,\x90\xb7p\xc4'   and at the end of the script the error message says "websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed."

Comment: I am sorry but I dont have the time to take a deeper look at it. A wild guess: The server is expecting  the client (you) to send something. Try this direction.

Comment: no worries you were already very helpful! that's what I think too. I've looked at the sent data within the frame tool in chrome and I have several "2" and "42" data so I guess I'll have to look this way. Anyway thx a lot again for your help balderman!

Comment: @j.downing hello have you been able to get deeper into this ?   ;-)